# Is it more efficient to have @ApplicationScoped beans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Let's say we have some stateless factory. Is it preferable to make it `@ApplicationScoped`?

In other words, should we make a bean as `@ApplicationScoped` only when we want to explicitly share its state among all clients or it is preferable also for stateless beans?

What are the best Java EE practice in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general principle: make everything as tightly-scoped as you can.

Unless you have some way of enforcing that your stateless bean remains stateless, one could accidentally add state, and then there is a problem.

Comment: Also, stateless implies "cheap to construct" to me, especially in the context of a factory. I know this is not necessarily the case - hence not adding to the answer - but if it's cheap to construct, it really doesn't matter if you're creating lots of instances.

Comment: Factory implies "not cheap to construct", though.

Comment: @Mick the things the factory constructs might not be cheap to construct; the factory itself typically is.

Comment: I have to disagree. You cannot imply much from the usage of a factory pattern. A persistence context is also a factory which produces entity managers. The persistence context is very expensive, the entity manager is not.